# Trying to return a char*/string after button clicked with CreateWindow in windows.h

Tags: c++, c, windows, window

Using windows.h i have the following windows created:

I think there is no need to write the obvious things that WINAPI WinMain needs.

```
textToWrite = CreateWindow("EDIT",
"",
WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
290, 70, 165, 20,
hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL
);

analize = CreateWindow("BUTTON",
"Analize",
WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
465, 70, 60, 20,
hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL
);

Result = CreateWindow("STATIC",
getResultFromWritenText(),
WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
290, 100, 235, 20,
hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL
);
```

I want that when "Analize" button is clicked, the "Result" static window returns something according to what the function `getResultFromWritenText()` returns. This is that i don't want the same text written as output (of textToWrite), but a new string/char* in base of an analysis of what was written by the user, knowing that `getResultFromWritenText()` function would know it and return it (whatever i want it to return) in the text field, not as a popup.

How can i do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

WINAPI takes null terminated c strings as arguments.  But [depending on compilation options for UNICODE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374131%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it uses either `char` or `wchar_t`.

So if you know in advance that you compile for UNICODE, you could make your function:

```
wstring getResultFromWritenText() { ... }
```

If you want to remain flexible you could define things as follows:

```
typedef basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;   // equivalen to string or wstring depending on options

tstring getResultFromWritenText() { ... }
```

Once you've done this, you can use the result of the function:

```
Result = CreateWindow("STATIC",
    getResultFromWritenText().data(),
    WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
    290, 100, 235, 20,
    hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I get your question, but you can't return text like so from CreateWindow(). 
If you want to set different text to the static window you have created after some button is pressed, do it like so:

in your window procedure:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
{
    if(lParam == (LPARAM)analize) // Your button is pressed
    {
        //If your getResultFromWritenText() function really returns some text...
        SendMessage(Result, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)getResultFromWritenText()); // Set new text to your static
    }
}
```